# Azure DevOps CICD build pipeline fails with error: specified command or file was not found

Tags: build, aws-lambda, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, aws-api-gateway

I have a CICD build pipeline in Azure Devops for building a .NET Core AWS API Gateway Serverless application. The Pipeline is using hosted Windows 2019. The step that fails is:

```
steps:
- task: AmazonWebServices.aws-vsts-tools.LambdaNETCoreDeploy.LambdaNETCoreDeploy@1
  displayName: 'Build solution and generate CloudFormation template. '
  inputs:
    awsCredentials: 'AWS - Development (Infrastructure)'
    regionName: 'ap-southeast-2'
    command: deployServerless
    packageOnly: true
    packageOutputFile: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)\serverless-output.yaml'
    lambdaProjectPath: testapi/LCSApi.csproj
    s3Bucket: 'api-dev-xxxxxxxx-s3'
    s3Prefix: 'azure_devops_builds/lcs/'
    additionalArgs: '-template serverless.template '
```

All I get from the error is the following:

```
Beginning Serverless Deployment
Performing package-only build of serverless application, output template will be placed in D:\a\1\a\serverless-output.yaml
"C:\Program Files\dotnet\dotnet.exe" lambda package-ci -ot D:\a\1\a\serverless-output.yaml --region ap-southeast-2 --s3-bucket api-dev-xxxxxx-s3 --s3-prefix azure_devops_builds/lcs/ --disable-interactive true -template serverless.template
Could not execute because the specified command or file was not found.
Possible reasons for this include:
  * You misspelled a built-in dotnet command.
  * You intended to execute a .NET Core program, but dotnet-lambda does not exist.
  * You intended to run a global tool, but a dotnet-prefixed executable with this name could not be found on the PATH.

##[error]Error: The process 'C:\Program Files\dotnet\dotnet.exe' failed with exit code 1
Finishing: Build solution and generate CloudFormation template.
```

However, if I re-run the pipeline straight after this failure, it works fine. Additionally, it does not always fail with this error. Around 70-80% of the time the pipeline works fine. What could this be and how can i address it?

Comment: Please set variable system.debug to True, to check whether there is more information in the log. In addition, when did you have this issue? Did you meet such issue before?

Comment: Any update to this issue? Does Krzysztof Madej's suggestion help you?

Comment: HI Cece, I have had this issue before, it is intermittent. I have added Krzysztof's suggestion today, and will monitor.

Comment: How's your issue going?

Answer (score 1):

Can you try adding this before your step:

```yaml
powershell: |
   dotnet tool install --global Amazon.Lambda.Tools --version 3.1.1
   dotnet tool update -g Amazon.Lambda.Tools
```